# TensorFlow warning: Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I run couple line of code for image classification using Keras and tensorflow libraries in terminal I got that error in my Mac device. I read some articles and some of them say tensorflow doesn't support the python 3.7 if so what should I do ?

```
tensorflow:From /Users/selimerhan/opt/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:3066: to_int32 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) 
  is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: 
    Use tf.cast instead. 2020-06-05 03:54:37.912219: I tensorflow/core/platform/
      cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary
      was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA Epoch 1/57
```

Comment: That is just a warning. If you want to use the complete set of CPU instructions you have to compile tensorflow from source. The default version of tensorflow is not built against your pc architecture so it might not use all available resources

Comment: Yes, it is a warning, not an error, and it has nothing to do with TensorFlow support of Python 3.7

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy 10/10 namechange

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon: retitled. In general any of you can and should edit mistaken titles, where they do not invalidate existing answers, or better still before they get answers which might hinder subsequent retitling.